# angular 2 destroy outlet-content and reload

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

is there a way in angular 2 to destroy a component which was created automatically inside an router-outet?

I want to destroy it that it will create a new one when I navigate to that outlet again (or is there finally a outlet-reload available?).

Answer (score 0):

because there is nothing included in the current angular 2 Version, i have a working Workaround.

In my case I want to destroy the outlet-component when my modal window Closes.

```
$('#mymodal_window').on("hide.bs.modal", ()=>{
    //destroy manually 
    for(var o of this.route.parent.children){

        if(o.outlet=="myoutletname")
        {
            var s:any = o.snapshot;
            s._routeConfig = null;
        }
    }
});
```

internally angular checks if the snapshots (it only compares the _routeConfig) are equal and will reuse the component. In my Workaround i simply delete the _routeConfig on window-close and the next time it will create a new instance of the component.